# TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined reading 'email'

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

```
router.post('/login', async (res, req) => {
    const{error} = loginValidation(req.body);
    if (error) return res.status(400).send(error.details[0].message);
    
    //user validation
    const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });
    if (!user) return res.status(400).send("Email doesn't exists");

    //checking password
    const validPass = await bcrypt.compare(req.body.password, user.password);
    if (!validPass) return res.status(400).send('Invalid Password')
    
    res.send("logged in");
});
```

The code is showing error ins this line body.email part :

const user = await User.findOne({ email: req.body.email });

[vscode error image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwGxA.png)

Comment: You have your `req` and `res`  mixed up, https://expressjs.com/en/starter/basic-routing.html

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You should do

res.body.email  on the place of req.body.email according to your code

Because in post async function you wrote (res, req) instead of (req, res)